# Copy rendered html with styles to outlook

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, outlook

I've implemented a simple splitview website which takes markdown as input, generates table of content and uses rect-markdown to render it as an formated HTML.

My goal is, to have a button which copies the formated result to the clipboard so that it can be pasted into an outlook e-Mail. If I copy the HTML on the website (not the raw html) and past it to Outlook it'll keep the styling but I couldn't manage it without manually selecting the rendered html as outlook doesn't interprete the raw html and would lose the styles with it.

How can I can I write the current rendered and formated html to the clipboard so that it is pasteable to outlook?